# Haskell servant: FormUrlEncoded request body with optional field

Tags: haskell, servant

Given the following servant server definition:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
  --resolver lts-19.10
  script
  --package base
  --package http-api-data
  --package lucid
  --package servant-lucid
  --package servant-server
  --package time
  --package warp
-}

{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Time
import GHC.Generics
import Lucid.Base
import Lucid.Html5
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Servant
import Servant.HTML.Lucid
import Web.FormUrlEncoded

data FormData = FormData {formTime :: Maybe TimeOfDay} deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromForm FormData

type API = "form" :> ReqBody '[FormUrlEncoded] FormData :> Post '[HTML] (Html ()) :<|> Get '[HTML] (Html ())

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ "starting on port " <> show port
  run port $ serve (Proxy @API) ((pure . toHtml . show) :<|> pure page)
  where
    port = 8080
    page = do
      doctype_
      html_ [lang_ "en"] $ do
        form_ [action_ "form", method_ "post"] $ do
          label_ [for_ "formTime"] "time"
          input_ [type_ "time", id_ "formTime", name_ "formTime"]
          input_ [type_ "submit", value_ "Submit"]
```

(This can be run as is using stack)

the time field in the parameter is supposed to be optional, so if the user doesn't provide a value for it, it should end up as `Nothing` in the `FormData` value that's passed to the Handler.
However, in the browser the field will be included in the request but with an empty value.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in servant or if it's intended behavior, but this does sound a bit counter-intuitive to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible solution I can think of is to wrap the `Maybe TimeOfDay` in a newtype that then implements the expected behavior in the `FromHttpApiData` instance, like so:

```hs
newtype MaybeTimeOfDay = MaybeTimeOfDay (Maybe TimeOfDay) deriving (Show)

instance FromHttpApiData MaybeTimeOfDay where
  parseQueryParam "" = Right (MaybeTimeOfDay Nothing)
  parseQueryParam t = MaybeTimeOfDay <$> parseQueryParam t

data FormData = FormData {formTime :: MaybeTimeOfDay} deriving (Generic, Show)
```

Or, more generically

```hs
newtype OptionalParameter a = OptionalParameter (Maybe a) deriving (Show)

instance FromHttpApiData a => FromHttpApiData (OptionalParameter a) where
  parseQueryParam "" = Right (OptionalParameter Nothing)
  parseQueryParam t = OptionalParameter <$> parseQueryParam t
```

This works but it feels a bit awkward to implement that manually.

Comment: I am running into this same issue now.  Quite unfortunate if you really have to wrap it.