# Htmx POST to haskell servant handling optional field in FormUrlEncoded request

Tags: rest, haskell, htmx, servant, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am using Htmx to POST a form to a Haskell Servant endpoint.  The endpoint has a model with a `FromForm` instance.  There is an optional field in the form.  If the field is excluded in the POST, the client will receive a 400 with response "Unexpected end-of-input, expecting -, +, or a digit", indicating the parsing failed.

```
-- | Reading model.
data Reading = Reading
  { title :: String
  , authors :: Vector String
  , startDate :: Day
  , endDate :: Maybe Day
  }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON, FromRow)

-- | Allow form construction of a `Reading` instance.
instance FromForm Reading where
  fromForm :: Form -> Either Text Reading
  fromForm f =
    Reading
      <$> parseUnique "title" f
      <*> (fromList <$> parseAll "authors" f)
      <*> parseUnique "startDate" f
      <*> parseMaybe "endDate" f
```

The actual FormUrlEncoded bytestring that gets POSTed is `title=asdf&authors=asdf&startDate=2024-03-01&endDate=` .  How can I work around this?  I suspect there is a way to make servant handle this elegantly, but I am also considering client side changes (althought that seems less ideal).

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199075/haskell-servant-formurlencoded-request-body-with-optional-field) but felt there must be an alternative to wrapping the `Maybe`.  Also, maybe there is something I can do through Htmx for my specific use case.

Comment: Not familiar with servant, but can't you just write your own parser? (honest question). Something in the line of `lookupMaybe "endate" >>= \mtext -> case mtext of {Just t | T.null t -> Nothing; Just t -> Just (parseQueryParams t); _ -> Nothing}`. I havent check the code... I don't  if it even compiles... But at the end of the day It should be a regular function `p :: Text -> Form -> Either Text (Maybe v)`

Comment: @Razumov I'd expect that `endDate=` would be parsed to the empty string?

Comment: @mb21 if you do a `lookupMaybe` instead of `parseMaybe` you get the empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I landed on a generic parser function with the signature suggested by @Ismor.

It works as expected, I imagine I will always use this in place of `parseMaybe` when handling incoming form data.

```
parseOptionalMaybe :: FromHttpApiData v => Text -> Form -> Either Text (Maybe v)
parseOptionalMaybe fieldName form = do
  maybeField <- lookupMaybe fieldName form
  case maybeField of
    Just "" -> return Nothing
    Just _ -> parseMaybe fieldName form
    Nothing -> return Nothing
```